How to get Instagram Messaging Bot approved?
I am trying to figure out how to approve an Instagram app which use instagram_basic and instagram_manage_messages.
I have created an app that offers to my customers a system to order and choose a Pick & Collect solution in my shops.
The app is working well in development mode but I keep getting rejection by Facebook Review team and I can't figure out why.
For instagram_basic, I have added this video: https://youtu.be/3kTJw-xegsY
And for instagram_manage_messages, this one: https://youtu.be/jvzUNG4q9qU
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

have exactly same issue - and they rejected with below statement:
provide in the application verification notes a test instruction on how we can integrate and provide Facebook account that has Instagram Business account connected so we can continue reviewing and replicate the functionality of the permission requested.
Did you found solution?
